# node.js & jade - making a post request and displaying the results in the same page without redirecting

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug

I have node.js express web application which performs the CRUD operations on a button click. Here I need to update a record based on the input from the user. For this, I need to input the detail from the user, display the existing values of the record in the same page, and prompt the user whether he wants to change the data.

If yes, then I need to input the values from the user and update it. Is it possible to have this in a single jade file where I am getting the input values from user.

jade file :

```
extends ../layout

block content
  .page-header
    h3 Updation

  form.form-horizontal(role='form', method='POST')
    h4 Enter the employee id for which you want to update the details
    input(type='hidden', name='_csrf', value=_csrf)

    .form-group
      label(class='col-sm-2 control-label', for='empid') Emp ID
      .col-sm-2
        input.form-control(type='text', name='empid', id='empid', autofocus=true)
     .form-group
      .col-sm-offset-2.col-sm-2
        button.btn.btn-primary(type='submit')
          i.fa.fa-pencil
          | Get details
```

I have this file where I am getting the employee id from user and making the post request. I am not sure how to render the response to this same page itself and prompt for changing details.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do this, but not with a form that gets submitted, because then your page is gone.

Instead, you can insert a button into your page that does an AJAX request to the backend, and on return of the AJAX request, you can dynamically replace some parts of your page with the returned data. Of course, you can include any data the user has entered into the AJAX request.

Since you want this all to happen in the frontend, you cannot do this in Jade. Instead, you need to add a script into your page that does what you want in the client's browser.

Here is an example of how to achieve this:

Put this in a file called *ajax.jade*:

```
mixin ajaxFunction
  script.
    function changeState(url, buttonid) {
      $.ajax({url: url}).done(function (data) {
        $('#' + buttonid).parent().html(data);
      });
    }

mixin ajaxButton(id, url, buttonLabel)
  a.btn.btn-primary.btn-xs.btn-block(id='#{id}',
        href='javascript:changeState(\'#{url}\', \'#{id}\')') #{buttonLabel}
```

Now you can put this mixin anywhere on your page. (Make sure the button id is unique across the whole page and does not contain spaces!). On click, it will replace itself with whatever the backend returned:

```
include ajax

+ajaxButton("myButton", "/some/url", "Klick me!")
```

Comment: I will try the way which you have mentioned. Meanwhile if you have any sample code for the same, can you post ?

Comment: Thank you Nicole. Sorry to get back to you late. I will surely check this out :)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if there's a way that the jade egine can partially render the jade template, If there is one way to do that, normally you can use Ajax to do this.
Form add submit event listener, in which you can set event.preventDefaut() to stop default submit process, in this way you can prevent page reloading.